# How add WS-Addressing Java >18

Tags: xml, soap, digital-signature

I have the next code that sign the XML but I can't found how add

```
        <wsa:To wsu:Id="id-90a9b727-0f12-4207-b360-b217352f30a6"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc</wsa:To>
```

wsu:Id="id-90a9b727-0f12-4207-b360-b217352f30a6" this something that create when the document is signed.

and already spend one week searching information but this is something that few companies use today.

Thanks by the help.

```
    public void signXML() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, WSSecurityException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException {

        String certFilePath = "./src/certificate/Certificado.pfx";
        String certPassword = "vqNw2eYpTY";
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(certFilePath), certPassword.toCharArray());
        String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin");
        properties.setProperty("org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", alias.toString());
        properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "PKCS12");
        properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", certPassword);
        properties.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", certFilePath);


        Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/purchaseOrder.xml"));

        WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader(document);
        secHeader.setMustUnderstand(false);
        secHeader.insertSecurityHeader();

        WSSecTimestamp timestamp = new WSSecTimestamp(secHeader);
        timestamp.setTimeToLive(300);
        timestamp.build();

        timestamp.prependToHeader();
        System.setProperty("org.apache.xml.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
        System.out.println("Crypto Obj:"+ crypto.getDefaultX509Identifier());

        WSSecSignature sign = new WSSecSignature(secHeader);
        sign.setX509Certificate(cert);
        sign.setUseSingleCertificate(true);
        sign.setUserInfo(alias.toString(), certPassword);
        sign.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
        sign.setSignatureAlgorithm(XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
        sign.setAddInclusivePrefixes(true);
        sign.setDigestAlgo(DigestMethod.SHA256);
        timestamp.prependToHeader();
        Document signedDoc = sign.build(crypto);

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("signedPurchaseOrder2.xml");
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(signedDoc), new StreamResult(os));
    }
```